# Python Logistic Regression Produces Wrong Coefficients

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, logistic-regression

I am trying to use LogisticRegression model fro scikit-learn to solve Excercise 2 from Machine Learning course by Andrew Ng on Coursera. But the result, which I get is wrong:

**1) Outcome coefficients doen't match with answers:**

What I get with a model

[image: LogisticRegression Outcome]

What I should get according to answers

[-25.16, 0.21, 0.20]

you can see on the plot (*wrong graph*), that decision boundary seems to be a little bit below the decision boundary by intuition.

**2) Graph outcome seems wrong**

As you can see, decision boundary is below

*LogisticRegression*
[image: LogisticRegression Plot]

*Answer*

[image: Answers Plot]

**MY CODE:**

```
% matplotlib notebook



# IMPORT DATA

ex2_folder = 'machine-learning-ex2/ex2'
input_1 = pd.read_csv(folder + ex2_folder +'/ex2data1.txt', header = None)
X = input_1[[0,1]]
y = input_1[2]


# IMPORT AND FIT MODEL

from sklearn.linear_model  import LogisticRegression
model = LogisticRegression(fit_intercept = True)
model.fit(X,y)
print('Intercept (Theta 0: {}). Coefficients: {}'.format(model.intercept_, model.coef_))



# CALCULATE GRID
n = 5

xx1, xx2 = np.mgrid[25:101:n, 25:101:n]
grid = np.c_[xx1.ravel(), xx2.ravel()]
probs = model.predict_proba(grid)[:, 1]
probs = probs.reshape(xx1.shape)


# PLOTTING

f = plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()


for outcome in [0,1]:
    xo = 'yo' if  outcome == 0 else 'k+'
    selection = y == outcome
    plt.plot(X.loc[selection, 0],X.loc[selection,1],xo, mec = 'k')
plt.xlim([25,100])
plt.ylim([25,100])

plt.xlabel('Exam 1 Score')
plt.ylabel('Exam 2 Score')
plt.title('Exam 1 & 2 and admission outcome')

contour = ax.contourf(xx1,xx2, probs, 100, cmap="RdBu",
                      vmin=0, vmax=1)
ax_c = f.colorbar(contour)
ax_c.set_label("$P(y = 1)$")
ax_c.set_ticks([0, .25, .5, .75, 1])

plt.contour(xx1, xx2, probs, [0.5], linewidths=1, colors='b', alpha = 0.3);

plt.plot(xx1[probs > 0.5], xx2[probs > 0.5],'.b', alpha = 0.3)
```

**LINKS**

[DataFile in txt](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kDRDQxHReE_pqDKnV-pZt-oSRComZuwn)

[PDF Tasks and Solutions in Octave](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1TmM7TbaC4JVufWptrHgDGIn7L55Ingja)

Comment: Adding a very high value for the `C` parameter will get you much closer: `model = LogisticRegression(C=1e10)`.

Answer (score 3):

To get identical results you need to create identical testing conditions.

One obvious difference at a glance is the iteration count. `Sklearn LogisticRegression` classifier default iteration count is 100, while Andrew NG's sample code runs for 400 iterations. That will certainly give you a different result from Nguyen's course.

I am not sure anymore which cost function Nguyen is using for the exercise, but I am pretty sure it's cross entropy and not the L2 that is default function for `LogisticRecression` classifier in `scikit learn`.

And the last note, before you implement higher-level solutions (scikitlearn/tensorflow/keras), you should first try to implement them in pure python to understand how they work. It will be easier (and more fun) to try and make higher-level packages to work for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
But even if LogisticRegression model is not the same, as Andrew model, result should be correct anyway? But as we can see on the graph - it is below anyway. In other words, if we bring this line 0.5 cm above, it will cover more dots and will not cover any crosses at all. So any cost function will be smaller for that outcome

Comment: Regression takes a step by step approach towards the true value. The output value depends on the cost function that calculates the `size of the step to move towards the true value`(the cost), a number of steps (iteration), etc. Thus with different numbers, you can arrive at different values (overfitting/underfitting), or get stuck in an incorrect `true value` (local minimum).  Thus to answer: it depends on the data and the parameters.

Comment: you can also try to tackel the problem from the other side. Try implementing L2 regulazation (sum of squares) instead of cross entropy on octave code and observe the result.